# Animate with leftt position doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have another problem with my mobile menu. It should work like this:

http://www.velux.pl/ (asp.net framework)

I try write logic to it in jquery, but it doesn't work properly. 
I want to have effect of sliding in and sliding out div with class service but it only shows and fades.
On some elements it is possible to animate properties like left or right but on elements with class service, it doesn't work. They all have given property: relative. So it's not a reason. In effect I don't have animation effect, elements only show and hide. In console property left is not modified at all.
I don't know why because on for example elements with class menu-header everything works fine.

Where is my mistake?

HTML (simple version)

```
<nav class="active">

                <div class="regular">
                    <ul class="open">
                        <li class="sub-menu ">
                            <div class="menu-item"> Produkty </div>
                            <div class="menu-header"> Produkty </div>
                            <ul class="innerTextMenu>
                                <li> <a class="menu-link" href="/produkty/okna-dachowe" target="">Okna dachowe</a> </li>
                                <li> <a class="menu-link" href="" target="">Okna do płaskiego dachu</a> </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu ">
                            <div class="menu-item"> Nasze wsparcie </div>
                            <div class="menu-header"> Nasze wsparcie </div>
                            <ul class="innerTextMenu">
                                <li> <a class="menu-link" href="/dla-klienta/serwis" target="">Obsługa posprzedażowa</a> </li>
                                <li> <a class="menu-link" href="/dla-klienta/zanim-kupisz" target="">Obsługa przedsprzedażowa</a> </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <ul class="level-1 service-menu">
                        <li class="sub-menu"> <a class="menu-link" href="http://www.veluxshop.pl" target="" onclick="dataLayer.push({'eventcategory': 'External links', 'eventaction': 'www.veluxshop.pl', 'eventlabel': 'undefined', 'event': 'eventga'});">Sklep z roletami</a> </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu"> <a class="menu-link" href="/dla-klienta/katalogi-i-broszury" target="">Znajdź katalog</a> </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu"> <a class="menu-link" href="http://prasa.velux.pl/" target="" onclick="dataLayer.push({'eventcategory': 'External links', 'eventaction': 'prasa.velux.pl', 'eventlabel': '/', 'event': 'eventga'});">Biuro prasowe</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

JQuery

```
    jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(a,b) {
    function cb(){ [b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
    return this.on("click", cb);
```

}

```
    $(".sub-menu").clickToggle(function() {   
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.menu-item').animate({'left':'-100%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
        $('.menu-header').css('right' , '0%');
        $('.service').addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.service').animate({'left:':'-100%'}, 'slow' , 'linear');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('.menu-item').animate({'left':'0%'}, 'slow', 'linear');
        $('.menu-header').css('right' , '-100%');
        $('.service').removeClass('is-hidden');
        $('.service').animate({'left:':'0%'}, 'slow' , 'linear');
     });
```

CSS

```
.is-hidden {
display: none !important;
transition:0.5s;
```

}

Unfortunately I can't add snippet becasue of large amount of code.

**On my site is seems in this way now:**

http://gbaniekty.pl/mobile-menu/index.html

Comment: can you create a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately there is a lot of css code because I use existing  css code  but I can send my whole code on server within an hour and I set a link to my test page.

Comment: I've give link to my page on test server.

Comment: Start by adding
 `<meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />` 
in the `<head>` . Then include all the css and js file required. Your test server is missing jquery-ui.min.css, animate.css, my.js, jquery-ui.min.js, jquery.js etc.